# Data ownership and performance

Tags: architecture

We're designing a new application and we ran into some architectural question when thinking about data ownership.

We broke down the system into components, for example Customer and Order. each of this component/module is responsible for a specific business domain, i.e. Customer deals with CRUD of customers and business process centered around customers (Register a n new customer, block customer account, etc.). each module is the owner of a set of database tables, and only that module may access them. if another module needs data that is owned by another module, it retrieves it by requesting it from that module.

So far so good, the question is how to deal with scenarios such as a report that needs to show all the customers and for each customer all his orders? in such a case we need to get all the customers from the Customer module, iterate over them and for each one get all the data from the Order module. performance won't be good...obviously it would be much better to have a stored proc join customers table and orders table, but that would also mean direct access to the data that is owned by another module, creating coupling and dependencies that we wish to avoid.

This is a simplified example, we're dealing with an enterprise application with a lot of business entities and relationships, and my goal is to keep it clean and as loosely coupled as possible. I foresee in the future many changes to the data scheme, and possibly splitting the system into several completely separate systems. I wish to have a design that would allow this to be done in a relatively easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is a good case for the repository pattern, where you define an interface (or a small number of them) that contains all the data logic. Implementations of this interface are then passed to components via an IoC.

This pattern doesnt entirly get around the coupling problem though, the reporting repository would have knowledge of the customer table, but atleast that knowledge would be contained to a small number of classes. (in theory you could put the reporting logic in the customer repository, but that is not the best practice, since users are more 'primitive' than reports, it depends on the system though and would mean less coupling)

You can get more info on the repository pattern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can have different owners (or ownership philosophies) for different levels of the solution.

It can make sense to apply ownership of data based on physical schema (although this won't always be the case).

Once you get to the business logic level you might have a whole new range of "owners" and scopes - these will own the "view" (slice of data) they are showing, but not the individual bits of data that make it up. I think this is completely fine.

Even at the Stored Procedure level this is fine.  Just because something is owned doesn't mean it can;t be shared.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest one of the two approaches here

- Using your example, if you are building an enterprise system with reporting needs, you should consider decoupling the reporting implementation from the code and leverages reporting framework to pull data from the data store and presenting it. You will make a conscious decision to bypass your business domain layer
- Second suggestion will be to create a new presentation domain layer that will services read-only data to your system, in this case it can get/prepare denormalised data or DTO specifically for the individual report needs. The backend data layer to provide this data can be stored procedure or other mechanism available to you in your programming environment (such as LINQ in .NET) that will give you the performance you need. All your transactional operation will still need to go through your business domain layer as the presentation layer only offers  read-only operation and object.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 *general* forms of object responsibilities - CRUD & read only. **Customer** and **Order** modules own their respective data (tables, rights, etc.) and occasionally share with others.

I would simply opt for the fastest, most efficient form of ownership possible - don't require **Report** module to ask for anything from your standard *business* modules. Your business modules are going to be laden with other responsibilities. Reports need to run as an independent module with its own set of rules, access, etc. using stored procedures as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I used an different approach to the same problem: Each module has it's own interfaces, correct? In this case, by interface you mean an programatic interface, like a EJB interface (in java), or a .h file (in old plain C), etc... But if you have a single database (even if the each module own a group of tables, you may have all of it a single database ) you can expose some part of your interface as a view in DB. In this case, each module will define a set of programatic interfaces, and a set of "DB interfaces", only for query purposes. You will be able to read data for your report using simple SQL and joins and only access what a module wants to expose.